# Multiple compression algorithms support in NestJs + Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, nestjs, nestjs-config, kafkajs

Im using NestJS + Kafka in the following way

```
  const appKafka = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<KafkaOptions>(KafkaModule, {
    transport: Transport.KAFKA,
    options: {
      client: {
        brokers: [`${getEnv("KAFKA_HOST")}:${getEnv("KAFKA_PORT")}`],
      },
      consumer: {
        groupId: "my_group_id",
        heartbeatInterval: 500,
      },
      run: {
        eachBatchAutoResolve: true,
      },
    },
  });
  await appKafka.listen();
  console.log("Kafka consumer service is listening!");
```

It is working fine but now I need to add support for Snappy compression algorithm. How can I do that? I would like to have support for both Snappy and Gzip. I know KafkaJS only have native support for Gzip but other compression algorithms can be easily implemented as shown in the [docs](https://kafka.js.org/docs/producing#snappy). What I have not figure out is how to do this involving with Nest. I would like to keep using `NestFactory.createMicroservice` instead of interacting with `KafkaJS` directly.

I have looked the `KafkaOptions` interface and haven't seen anything useful. Does anybody knows how to do this?